# How to refresh b-table component without resetting the pagination?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, buefy

I am currently using the Vue.js framework along with buefy (0.9.2) for the UI components.The issue here is that the b-table component is not updating sometimes on the page/ui when I click the delete icon(deletes that row from the table) or when I click the add new row button. I can confirm that the operations(delete and add row) themselves are working perfectly.(I verified this using a console log and also by inspecting the vuex store.Its just that the change is not reflecting in the page/ui.

Template example-

```
 <b-table
      ref="records"
      :data="this.objectData.records"
      :hoverable="true"
      :paginated="true"
      :per-page="10"
      selectable
      @select="selected"
      detailed
      :show-detail-icon="true"
      icon-pack="mdi"
      custom-row-key="id"
    >  
  <b-table-column   v-slot="props" field="effectiveDate" label="Eff Date">{{ props.row.effectiveDate }}</b-table-column>
        <b-table-column   v-slot="props" field="jobType" label="Job Type">{{ props.row.jobType }}</b-table-column>
        <b-table-column   v-slot="props" field="action" label="Action">{{ props.row.action }}</b-table-column>   
        <b-table-column   v-slot="props">
          <b-button class="is-borderless is-borderless" @click="deleteTableRow('records','records',props.index)">
            <b-icon icon="delete"></b-icon>
          </b-button>        
        </b-table-column>
```

function that performs the delete row operation operation-

```
 deleteTableRow(tableRef, dataCol, index) {
                this.objectData[dataCol].splice(index, 1);   
            },
```

NOTE: I have also tried using a key prop and incrementing this key  in the delete row function to force refresh the b-table component,but the issue here is that it resets the pagination back to the 1st page.So what should I do in order to refresh the b-table component without re-setting the pagination back to the 1st page?

Answer (score 0):

I used `:key` property to re-render entire table - it was enough for my case. Not sure about pagination (probably might be solved in similar way). Code sample:

```
  data () {
    return {
      tableDataKey: 0,
      ...
```

and:

```
    <b-table
      ref="table"
      :key="tableDataKey"
      :data="tableData"
      ...
```

then - when table has to be re-rendered, just change/update the key:

```
    if(refreshIsRequired) {
        this.tableDataKey++
    }
```

this will cause component redraw. The same approach might be applied to any component.

More about the [key-changing-technique](https://michaelnthiessen.com/key-changing-technique/) and generally about the `key` attribute in: [understanding-the-key-attribute](https://michaelnthiessen.com/understanding-the-key-attribute/) - great articles written by **Michael Thiessen**

P.S. `buefy` *v.0.9.2* used with `nuxtjs` *v.2.15.0*